# Input tools for each Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck on this case. Each textareas should have own toolbox. For now only one is active (I expect more than 2 areas, so JavaScript should recognize by ID)

I've tried use something like:

```
function getID(id) {
        var $ta = id; }
```

but, no luck.

The code:

HTML

```
<div id="1">
<input type="button" id="1" class="unselectable" unselectable="on" style="font-weight:bold" name="bold" value="B">
    <input type="button" id="1" class="unselectable" unselectable="on" style="font-style: italic;" name="italic" value="I">

    <br><textarea id="comment_1" name="comment" aria-required="true"></textarea>
  </div>

<div id="2">
<input type="button" id="2" class="unselectable" unselectable="on" style="font-weight:bold" name="bold" value="B">
    <input type="button" id="2" class="unselectable" unselectable="on" style="font-style: italic;" name="italic" value="I">

    <br><textarea id="comment_2" name="comment" aria-required="true"></textarea>
  </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


            $("input").mousedown(function(e) {
                var $ta = $("#comment_"+this.id);

            var $startIndex = $("#startIndex"), $endIndex = $("#endIndex");

            function reportSelection() {
                var sel = $ta.getSelection();
                $startIndex.text(sel.start);
                $endIndex.text(sel.end);
            }

            $(document).on("selectionchange", reportSelection);
            $ta.on("keyup input mouseup textInput", reportSelection);

            $ta.focus();

            reportSelection();



                e.preventDefault();
                switch (this.name) {


                   case "bold":
                        $ta.surroundSelectedText("**", '**');
                        break;
                    case "italic":
                        $ta.surroundSelectedText("_", '_');
                        break;
                     case "quote":
                        $ta.surroundSelectedText("{", '}');
                        break;


                }

                $ta.focus();

                // For IE, which always shifts the focus onto the button
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    $ta.focus();
                }, 0);
            });

        });
```

Comment: You use the id 'comment' for both text fields, which is not allowed. It also causes that each button will write to the first field. You'll want to either detect the textfield after the buttons, or mark the buttons in some way so they know which textfield they belong to. (data-attribute?)

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `id` should be unique. if not, however, `$('#comment')` will only select the first element with `id=comment`. In this case, you may use `class` instead of `id`.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this :)

```
 var $ta = $("#comment_"+this.id);
```

resolution:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjROJv